# Mudblazor and C# how do I use multiple validation methods in a MudTextfield

Tags: c#, mudblazor

I have the following line of code which uses a mud textbox I also have the following c# validation:

How can I call my two methods in the validation tag:

`<MudTextField @bind-Value="@golfReg.ContactNumber" Required="true" Label="Contact Number" Variant="Variant.Filled" Margin="Margin.Dense" Style="@($"color:#00679F;background:{Colors.Shades.White};")" Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(PhonNumberLength))" />`

```
private IEnumerable<string> PhonNumberLength(string ContactNumber) {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactNumber)) {
            yield return "Contact Number is required!";
            yield break;
        }
        if(ContactNumber.Length > 13) {
            yield return "Contact Number must be a max length of 13 digits";
        } else if(ContactNumber.Length < 10) {
            yield return "Contact Number must be a min length of 10 digits";
        } else if(!ContactNumber.All(c => char.IsDigit(c))) {
            yield return "Contact Number must only contain numeric values";
        }
    }

    public bool CheckForOnlyNumbers(string input)
    {
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's various ways to do this. I'd recommend using [FluentValidation](https://mudblazor.com/components/form#using-fluent-validation).

To make your specific code work however, you just need to call the other method from the main method set on `MudTextField` -> `Validation` property.

In the example below, I've created a new method `ValidateContactNumber` that calls both of your validation logic methods.

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@_golfReg.ContactNumber" Required="true" 
                Label="Contact Number" Variant="Variant.Filled" Margin="Margin.Dense"
                Style="@($"color:#00679F;background:{Colors.Shades.White};")"
                Validation="@(new Func<string, IEnumerable<string>>(ValidateContactNumber))" />

@code{
    private IEnumerable<string> ValidateContactNumber(string contactNumber)
    {
        if(!CheckForOnlyNumbers(contactNumber))
        {
            yield return "Contact Number must be only numbers";
        }
        foreach (var result in PhoneNumberLength(contactNumber))
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> PhoneNumberLength(string contactNumber) {

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contactNumber)) {
            yield return "Contact Number is required!";
            yield break;
        }
        if(contactNumber.Length > 13) {
            yield return "Contact Number must be a max length of 13 digits";
        } else if(contactNumber.Length < 10) {
            yield return "Contact Number must be a min length of 10 digits";
        } else if(!contactNumber.All(c => char.IsDigit(c))) {
            yield return "Contact Number must only contain numeric values";
        }
    }

    public bool CheckForOnlyNumbers(string contactNumber)
    {
        foreach (char c in contactNumber)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(c))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOwdOZuzyzUIihUg)